# Convert groupBYKey to ReduceByKey Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

How to convert groupbyKey to reduceByKey in pyspark. I have attached a snippet. This will apply a corr for each region dept week combination. I have used groupbyKey, but its very slow and Shuffle error (i have 10-20GB of data and each group will have 2-3GB).  Please help me in rewriting this using reduceByKey

Data set

```
region dept week val1 valu2
 US    CS   1     1    2
 US    CS   2     1.5  2
 US    CS   3     1    2
 US    ELE  1     1.1  2
 US    ELE  2     2.1  2
 US    ELE  3     1    2
 UE    CS   1     2    2
```

output

```
region dept corr  
US      CS  0.5
US      ELE 0.6
UE      CS  .3333
```

Code

```
def testFunction (key, value):
   for val in value:
        keysValue = val.asDict().keys()
        inputpdDF.append(dict([(keyRDD, val[keyRDD]) for keyRDD in keysValue])
   pdDF = pd.DataFrame(inputpdDF, columns = keysValue)
   corr = pearsonr(pdDF['val1'].astype(float),  pdDF['val1'].astype(float))[0]
   corrDict = {"region" : key.region, "dept" : key.dept, "corr": corr}                
   finalRDD.append(Row(**corrDict))
   return finalRDD

resRDD = df.select(["region", "dept", "week", "val1",  "val2"])\
           .map(lambda r: (Row(region= r.region, dept= r.dept), r))\
           .groupByKey()\
           .flatMap(lambda KeyValue: testFunction(KeyValue[0], list(KeyValue[1])))
```

Comment: reduceByKey is different to groupByKey in a few ways but the main one is the difference between aggregate - groupby yields (key,<iterable>) whilst reduce produces (key,aggregate e.g sum of <iterable>). So to re-write from one to the other means understanding how we can have a single pass (aggregator) function over the data. note that I have not bothered to look at your "test function".

Comment: @Chinny84 sorry i missed the required out put format earlier. Is it possible to guide me on alternative approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import corr
>>> df.groupBy("region", "dept").agg(corr("val1",  "val2"))
```

Comment: Thanks , this will work..i copied only 2  columns .. actually my corr calculation should happen with val1 with Val2, val1 with val3, ,val1 with val4 ... val1 with Valn (nth column)  i am planning to do like this  aggList = [func.corr("val1", col).alias(colname)  for col in columns ]    df.groupBy("region", "dept").agg(*aggList) .... I feel this should work . Next bigger trouble is i have to apply statsmodels.formula.api.ols () to same group which is very slow with groupByKey approach. Do we have any other way? I tried MLLIB which wont work for us (i need  closed form solution )

Comment: You can perform multiple aggregates. I cannot help with formula.